How can I capture the row and column of the user click on the terminal and decode the signal in GNU Bash
I found how to capture the row and column of the user click on the terminal using:
echo -en '\033[?1000h'

However, what it gives is something like this:
\033[M �6\033[M#�6

I googled how to decode that string of text, and asked AI, and found no answer.
